# InStr skipping cells with large character count (255+)

Tags: excel, vba

Having some issues with `InStr` skipping cells with large character counts (255+). 
It is skipping over these cells for SubString comparison.

The same `InStr` function is working for cells with lower character counts within the same FOR LOOP. So I know that it not a coding issue, but rather a limitation of the max String size for the `InStr` function.

Is there a way to get InStr to work with large character count cells? (255+)

Example Code:

```
If InStr(CStr(Sheet2.Cells(i, 18)), CStr(IssueComboBoxStr)) > 0 Then
```

Comment: Mmmm, tried with cells with more than 300 characters and Instr worked perfect for me.  The only diference is that i typed a Start number, and also typed a compare option (in my case it was `vbTextCompare`)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Find function.

```
If Not Sheet2.Cells(i,18).Find(Cstr(IssueComboBoxStr),lookat:=xlPart) is Nothing
```

Answer (score 0):

You may need to examine the strings very closely.

In this demo, `sBig` contains 5000 characters and `sNotSoBig` contains 4996 characters.  `InStr()` has no problem finding the "little" string within the "big" string:

```
Sub TestInStr()
    Dim sBig As String, sNotSoBig As String
    Dim i As Long

    sBig = ""
    For i = 1 To 500
        sBig = sBig & "1234567890"
    Next i

    sNotSoBig = Mid(sBig, 5)

    MsgBox Len(sBig) & vbCrLf & Len(sNotSoBig) & vbCrLf & InStr(1, sBig, sNotSoBig)
End Sub
```

[image]

We will need more details to help you debug the issue.

Comment: ...As a 61k user, why would you post an answer that essentially says the problem can't be reproduced, *which is a close reason*?